# How to write an array in a text file in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, text, text-files

I have fixed my previous problem with getting the layout of the text, however I am struggling with creating an array and ordering the values from high to low. This is my current code:

```
print("Please type in a username")
username = str(input())
print("Please enter the score you would like to enter")
newscore = input()
userfile = open("%s.txt" %(username), "a+")
userfile.write(", " + newscore)
highscore = userfile.read().split(",")
highscore.sort()
print ("Your highscore is :", highscore[0])
userfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually tell it what you want it to write.  If you want it to write a comma and a space, then you need to tell it so:

```
userfile.write(", " + newscore)
```

and if you want to sort the array, you will need to read the file into an array and then call a method to do the sort.

The following should accomplish what you seek:

```
userfile.close()
userfile = open("%s.txt" %(username))
array = userfile.read().split(", ")
array.sort(reverse=True)
```